# Replacing an old oven

Tags: kitchens, oven, range

I have an old oven that does not work any more. I need to replace it with a new one.

As you can see, this is not a modern cooking range where the stove is right on top of the oven.

What do I need to take into consideration in finding a new oven?

Here is a picture of the product code
[image]

Here is a picture of the oven

[image]

Comment: Thought you said you had an old oven.  No wonder you need to replace it, with all those new fangle push bottons.  Usually only thing people care much about is if the new oven/stove will fit in the space.  Might need to upgrade the electric cable/circuit, if new one takes more power.

Comment: Yanno, if you like the one you have, getting it fixed is a reasonable path.  These aren't rocket ships - Parts rarely cost more than $50 for appliances.  It's labor that gets ya...

Comment: If anything, I would say "separates" cooktop and oven are more deluxe.  It can give you best of both worlds: gas for range and electric for oven.  (in gas ovens the combustion products [water and CO2] can cause too much humidity inside the oven, and affect baking).

Comment: As @KyleB noted, parts can be reasonably priced and are (or were, at least) generally available online, along with videos showing how to disassemble, replace & reassemble. _If_ you like the oven you've currently got. If it's just time for an update, well, by all means!

Comment: According to GE's website, this model was manufactured between 1998-2001. They show that some parts are readily available but others are not, so whether it's repairable will definitely depend on what the problem is.

Answer (score 5):

This looks like a relatively recent (probably less than 25 years old) oven. That being said, depending on what is wrong with it, replacement may be the best solution. Since the control panel does light up, it isn't totally dead.

In any case, combination cooktop/oven is very common but is not "modern" in any sense - both cooktop/oven together and separate have been common in the US for a long time. It comes down to personal preference. My house had separate, but both electric, but I kept them separate when redoing my kitchen so that I could switch to gas for the cooktop while keeping the oven electric, and eventually replacing the single oven with a double oven. Single ovens are readily available (subject to general supply issue affecting everything lately) and a straight replacement should not be a problem. The main issue is the dimensions - height and width of the cabinet. (Depth is almost always based on 24" deep cabinets in the US.) I'm not sure how standardized the heights are. Widths are typically 24", 27" and 30". Secondary to that is color - most manufacturers offer black (as you have), white, almond/beige/biscuit and stainless steel. And then you pick features: self-cleaning and convection are probably the most popular major differences between models - your current oven has both of those features.

Power supply is important. Your existing oven uses 3.4kW in a 240V installation. That's only 15A, so the circuit could be as small as 20A. Check the breaker to see what you actually have, as a new oven may need a larger circuit.

Answer (score 1):

What to look for:

1- how is the old connected to the wall (a Plug or wired), compare the plugs.

2- The dimensions (will it fit)

3- The power requirements (read the label (kW) on the new one), you might need an upgrade, or not.

4- Open the circuit breaker box and look for Oven one (maybe marked) is it one or two circuit breakers joined together, and how many amps it says on the breaker.

Comment: Nearly all US ovens are supposed to be 4 wire. Old connections often 3 wire. Sometimes easy to move to 4 wire and sometimes not. Most ovens come with instructions for 3 and 4 wire connections. Bottom line is old connection type usually not a big deal as long as it is 120/240 (which means it has neutral) and then really a question of circuit size.

Answer (score 1):

That's what's called a "wall oven" (even when mounted below a counter top)

You can still get this type of appliance new.